# How to improve fit of distribution to data

Tags: goodness-of-fit, fitting, gamma-distribution, lognormal-distribution

I'm trying to fit one of common expenential distributions to data using histfit. However it seems that results aren't as good as expected - it seems that peak should be higher. Histograms presents time interval of occurence of some event versus number of occurences. I tried *histfit* for Gamma and lognormal distributions.

My question is if is there a way to get better fit for this data? Does number of bins have infulence on result? (maybe better to use *fitdistr*?) Maybe I can somehow modify fitting funtion to have other cost function and thus get better fit? My goal is to have as good fit as possible.

I'm using Matlab but I can use R as well if necessary.
Data (time intervals) is [here](https://pastebin.com/4sJx0eBi).

Results are presented on figure below:
[image: Gamma and lognormal fits]

*Clarification:*
In response to questions about the goal of this study: The data describes process of intervals between vehicles in traffic. I've got several dozens of data files of this kind, all are similar to this one, presented data is good representative. My goal is to fit distribution so I can sample data of this kind.

Comment: One consideration is, whatever fit you find using the data in hand, there is the question of how good the fit will be for fresh data.  Think of it like a bias-variance tradeoff of sorts.

Comment: Is there an absolute need for a parametric probability distribution?  Why not use a nonparametric density estimation approach?  In *R* try `density`.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? How does having a good fit to some distribution help you?

Comment: I fit the data to 90 continuous statistical distributions from scipy, and the best fit is the Johnson SU with probability distribution function johnsonsu.pdf(x, a, b) = b / sqrt(x**2 + 1) * phi(a + b * log(x + sqrt(x**2 + 1))) with parameters a = -9.5986275412769373E-01, b = 9.2348670873599736E-01, location = 7.8170258336468734E+01 and scale = 3.1547621097089326E+01 The scipy documentation link for this distribution is http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsu.html

Comment: @Sycorax has given the best response so far in a comment by asking *why*: what is this procedure intended to accomplish? One thing we can guarantee is that no matter how many "known" unimodal distribution functions you try to fit to these data, the fit will be poor.  In this sense the question is a little like asking what brand of jeans would best fit an octopus. Even in such cases there can be merit to the distribution-fitting exercise, *provided we can learn why the data depart from the fit.*  But to help you with that we need to understand the data and to have your answer to the "why?".

Comment: Good point - I put clarification in bottom of the question. 

@JamesPhillips - did you test it automatically? Is there a tool to do that?

Comment: To answer your question: I used my online, open source statistical distribution fitter at http://zunzun.com/StatisticalDistributions/1/

Comment: On the subject that @Sycorax mentions ("What problem are you trying to solve?")...Do you have multiple samples from different populations that you need a family of distributions so that comparing estimates of common parameters makes sense?  If that family has more than a few parameters and there's no known rationale for why that family is appropriate, then you'd be better off choosing some summary statistics to compare (like the mean, 75th percentile, median, semi-interquartile range, etc.) among the populations of interest.  My comment is just to provide a more explicit example of the "Why".

Comment: @JimB right, is to be re-thinked what really is my goal. Thanks for suggestions. All the answers in this topic gave me enough knowledge so I'm able to continue my research. Once I find which approach is best for this problem, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cut / pasted individual observations from the link provided. A distribution
ID program yielded essentially the same 'best fit' as @JamesPhillips mentions. 
The binning of the histogram has nothing to do with such distribution ID
procedures, which use individual observations.

In R, `density` with the default KDE at 1.5 the default bandwidth gave
the red curve below. (The KDE may *look* like it is smoothing the histogram, but it is determined independently of the histogram.) 
Perhaps @JimB's suggestion is best, unless there
is something clear to be gained from having a name to attach to an
approximating density.

[image]

Depending on your objectives, perhaps it is useful to try to understand
the mechanism that produces these data. Is it possible that the distribution
we're observing is a mixture of several simpler distributions? In particular, I suspect that the outliers at the far right (beyond about 300) are interfering with distribution
ID. Do you
think they could be noise unrelated to the
process under study, or do you suppose they are inherent in the process?

```
x = c(135,346,363,351,154,82,147,...,52,81,14,733,872,730,600)

 hist(x,br=20, prob=T, ylim=c(0,0.008), col="skyblue2")
 rug(x)
 lines(density(x, from=0, to=500, adj=1.5), col="red", lwd=2)

 summary(x); sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0    89.0   119.0   147.6   163.5   872.0 
 [1] 109.4539
```

**Addendum:** Truncating the data to values between 10 and 300 I got
semi-promising probability plots for Weibull and Gamma distributions.
(Plots look vaguely plausible but data fail Anderson-Darling GOF tests.)
Such fussing with data to 'get a fit' is a potentially endless and pointless game,
but I couldn't resist one more try. Please seriously consider @whuber's Comment. (Partial Minitab output.)

```
  N    Mean   StDev  Minimum     Q1  Median      Q3  Maximum
348  124.01   54.86    10.00  86.00  111.50  150.00   288.00

Distribution    Shape      Scale
Weibull       2.39387  140.03773
Gamma         4.99392   24.83193
```

[image]

Comment: I put clarification in bottom of the question. I don't know what kind of distribution or mix of distributions can it be. Exponential were my guess. Outliers can be ingored, but rather the ones beyond 500.

According to your solution and my clarification - if I fit this distribution to several data sets, can I then get it's parameters (having in mind fact that it is non-parametric distribution) to calculate parameters of one averaged distribution?

Comment: Interarrival times between events are indeed often exponential. Sometimes gamma, which are sums of exponentials (of same rate). In theoretical discussions, exponential is often used because (a) mathamatically simple, (b) no-memory property implies no need to take past history into account. Key question to ask in appl is whether you really believe the no-memory (Markovian) property holds true. // If you have several datasets that are truly from a common process, you may do better by merging them. // Remaining unanswered question is what benefit there really is to knowing the name of the dist'n.

Comment: There's no benefit in knowing the name of distribution, the benefit here is getting good fit. If I suggested anyhwere that name is important, it is wrong.
I think that in this process memory may have some little influence, but I think it can be assumed that there is no-memory.